# Add currency to the number

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 var val = string.Format("{0:N}", 34567.88);
 var cul = val.ToString("{0:c}",culture);
```

ToString is throwing error: no overload for method tostring takes 2 arguments

I can do directly also but it is not giving valid output

```
var Total = string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", 34567.88);
```

Output is: $3.4567,88

Comment: what output you want ?

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: Output should be: $3,4567.88

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you pass to `culture`, but if you try this, you will get desired output:

```
var Total = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), "{0:C}", 34567.88);
```

Comment: I already did this. but not getting desired output. Do you have any alternative solution for that

Comment: String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", 34567.88); give me desire output